# regex to allow alphanumeric characters on both sides of an equal sign?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I need a regular expression to validate whether text entered in an asp.net textbox has the following format

```
A-za-z123456789  /s = /s  A-za-z123456789
```

Regular expression explained:

- one or more alphanumeric characters
- followed by any number of spaces
- an equal sign
- followed by any number of spaces
- one or more alphanumeric characters

Comment: You've done most of the work already; what are you having trouble with?

Comment: I cant get it to work, thats why im here asking for help.

Comment: Can there be _no_ alphanumeric chars and/or spaces and just a `=`? Is `0` valid?

Comment: no, there can be 0 spaces but there has to be alphanumeric chars on both sides of an equal sign.

Comment: Can zero be one of the alphanums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If zero valid

```
"^[a-zA-Z\\d]+\\s*=\\s*[a-zA-Z\\d]+$"
```

If zero not valid

```
"^[a-zA-Z1-9]+\\s*=\\s*[a-zA-Z1-9]+$"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*\=\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

Replace * with + if you want one or more rather than "any" (which includes zero)

Considering your answer to the comment about requiring one or more alphanumeric characters each side:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*\=\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

This version will only match if there is at least one alphanumeric character each side of the "=".